# What is the difference between URI and URL in HttpClient

Tags: url, uri, apache-httpclient-4.x

In the sample code below, when would the uri not equals with url?

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
String url = "http://domain/path1/path2"
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(toFetchURL);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

String uri = get.getURI.toString();
if (!uri.equals(url)) {
    // when would this happen?
    // some logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

URL is a subset of URI. so a URL can be converted to URI, but URI can't convert to URL.